# Exclude user_home directory from Header Search Paths list

Tags: cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

Clion always tries to index my `USER_HOME` directory and it takes much time to complete. Deleting line `<root url="file://$USER_HOME$" />` in project iml file give effect, but it continues while cmake project is not reloaded. When it happens something external change iml file back and return `<root url="file://$USER_HOME$" />` line.

How to exclude this directory forewer? "Mark directory as" does not exist in popup menu. CLion 2016.2. Win10

Comment: Do you include this directory in your CMake files?
Do you see it in the Project View toolwindow?

Comment: @nastasiak2512  I didn't understand what do you mean under CMake files.

Comment: Do you have a CMake-based project?

Comment: @nastasiak2512 Yes, it's default for Clion projects. Only what I have and can edit - project CMakeLists.txt and CMake Cache Variables. One interesting thing - this project shared to my teammate with the same settings but he doesn't have problems with indexing like me.

Comment: Do you include your UDER_HOME somewhere in CMake? With `include_directories` or other command?
Also do you see this directory in the project view toolwindow?

Comment: @nastasiak2512 No, I didn't include, checked it and don't see this directory in project view, only in "External Libraries/Header Search Paths". I have a suspicion that this problem may be due to installed Pycharm on my computer, for example very often when I'm trying to create new header/class in Clion I see PyCharm creation menu instead of Clion: http://prnt.sc/c36lrb

Comment: Do you actually include any headers from this directory?
Do you run PyCharm and CLion simultaneously on one project?

Comment: @nastasiak2512 I'm sorry for this pause. No I didn't include headers from this directory, but project located in `C:/User_Home/ClionProjects`. No, I use PyCharm and Clion on different projects. I saw your profile and decied, maybe, if you're helping in accordance with your position in Jetbrains, we can relocate this dialogue in another messager, maybe it will be more convenient. Thank you!

Comment: easiest way is to relocate to our support. Submit a request here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us and link to the thread. I'll follow up there. Thanks.

Comment: And sorry, I'm not getting notifications from here properly. So missing messages from time to time.

Comment: @nastasiak2512 Thank you for helping) Don't apologize, its not your fault)